# How to grab object id from UITableView and delete object based on object id?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

Now I got problem with this one, I don't know how to grab object id from UITableView after user select from it and pass it into another view controller, I want to delete the object based on object id that I already fetch from previous one. All the data come from `user` entity.

UITableView

```
var myList: Array <AnyObject> = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        /* grab object id here from core data object and pass to NSUserDefault*/
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(objectId, forKey: "userId")

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let deleteViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("accessView") as DeleteViewController
        self.presentViewController(deleteViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }
```

DeleteViewController

```
 let objectId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId")
/* Grab object id from NSUserDefault and delete object here*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the answer.

UITableView

```
var myList: Array <AnyObject> = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let data: NSManagedObject = myList[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject

        let userId = data.valueForKeyPath("userId") as? String
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(objectId, forKey: "userId")

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let deleteViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("accessView") as DeleteViewController
        self.presentViewController(deleteViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }
```

DeleteViewController

```
let userId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId")

                    //reference to our app delegate
                    let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
                    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

                    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EntityOne")
                    request.includesSubentities = false
                    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
                    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userId = %@", userId!)
                    let items = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

                    for item in items {
                        context.deleteObject(item as NSManagedObject)
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this with two functions, one to fetch the specific user and one to delete the user. Now these methods assume that each object will have a unique id, so using the following functions you just call `deleteUser(fetchUser(someID))`

```
func fetchUser(id: Int) -> User? {

    // Define fetch request/predicate
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == \(id)")

    // Assign fetch request properties
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 1
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

    // Handle results
    let fetchedResults = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)

    if fetchedResults?.count != 0 {

        if let fetchedUser: User = fetchedResults![0] as? User {
            return fetchedUser
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Delete
func deleteUser(id: Int) {
    if let user = fetchEvent(id) {
        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(user)
    }
}
```